# What to do with the overflow in a binary subtraction

Tags: binary

I have a question regarding the overflow of a result in a binary subtraction of two complements binary numbers.

12(2TC) = 00001100

-10(2TC) = 11110110

After having performed the addition, I have this result : 100000010 
The MSB is obviously an overflow, but is it normal? Should I get rid of it and therefore keep only the 8 other bits? 
The result would be : 00000010 which is correct because it's 2 in decimal base.

Thanks,

Comment: https://courses.cs.vt.edu/csonline/NumberSystems/Lessons/SubtractionWithTwosComplement/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The answer is right 100000010. The MSB is to tell whether the number is -ve or not when using the signed representation.
So in signed representation:

+2 = 000000010

-2 = 100000010

You need a way to differentiate between + and - number and MSB bit is used for that purpose.

Also in signed representation the number range is  -2^8 to 2^8. (Ignoring 1's in the ranges). 
But if your representation would have been unsigned, then your range would have 
0-2^9.

Comment: In signed representation the range is actually `-2^7 - 2^7-1`, and unsigned is `-2^8 - 2^8-1`.

Comment: @mbomb007 the ranges you provided are ranges when we work under assumption of 8 bit system. But My explanation was trying to explain the question and the numbers used in the question. Because all this is true for n bit system